# How to find mean ( averaging of Pixels ) of 15 consecutive color images( Live webcam video ) using Opencv?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

How to find mean (i.e Averaging of Pixels ) of 15 consecutive color frames using Opencv ?

At the End I want to an image where its " Averaging of 15 consecutive Images ".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV `Mat` supports various [matrix expressions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrix-expressions), including addition and scaling.

That said, you can just do:

```
vector<Mat> mats(15); // images that you want to average
...
Mat average = zeros(mats[0].size(), CV_32FC3); 
        // use float type here to avoid overflow
        // , and assume all images are 3 channels
for (int i=0; i<mats.size(); i++)
     average = average + mats[i];
average = average*(1.0f/15);
```

Comment: Could you please add few lines of code too.. while reading every frames of video, do i need to dump in the mats. is that what you meant?? ( in the first line )

Comment: @RoboMe The provided code should work if you already have the images.

Comment: I am newbie to image processing, Where you are reading the first 15 frames in the above code.

Comment: Showing exception error - while `for (int i=0; i<mats.size(); i++)
  average = average + mats[i];` My full source code `int nFrameCount = 0;
 vector<Mat> mats(15);
 while(1)
 {  
  cap>>mats[nFrameCount];
  nFrameCount++;

  if(nFrameCount == 15)
   break; 
 }
 Mat average = Mat::zeros(mats[0].size(), CV_32FC3);

 for (int i=0; i<mats.size(); i++)
  average = average + mats[i];

 average = average*(1.0f/15);`

Comment: @RoboMe Make sure you video capture opens successfully, i.e make sure `cap>>mats[nFrameCount];` works fine.

Comment: i saved as image `cap>>mat[nFrameCount]` is reading properly.. please see the error **First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD05940D in StartMt1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000026D470.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.**                                                                `for (int i=0; i<mats.size(); i++)   average = average + mats[i];`

Comment: @RoboMe What will happen if you press **continue**?

Comment: @RoboMe Try all-the-way **continue**.

Comment: no getting same error. please suggest some other way to achieve this.

Comment: @RoboMe Actually you can disable exceptions by setup options here: **Alt+Del+E**.

Comment: image Step are different please see here. ` Mat average = Mat::zeros(mats[0].size(), CV_32F);` after this step i check the image step.. ** Newly created average is getting (2560,4 ) ** our Original image ** mat[0] - contains [1920,3] ** There is image depth/step ..this could be the problem ..

Comment: What's the types of these images? If they have 3 channels, `average` should be of type `CV_32FC3`, not `CV_32F`.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert all the images to a float because integer formats overflow after 255:

```
src.convertTo(dst, CV_32F);
```

Then, all you need to do is add the images together:

```
Mat canvas = //create an image here;
add(canvas, frame, canvas);
```

And after 15 frames divide by 15:

```
canvas.mul(1/15.0);
```